# gradle how get info about project (dependecies artifactID) on Java

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

In Gradle i can get project info (dependencies, artifact, and group id's) on Groovy like this:

```
class TestPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
        @Override
        void apply(Project project) {
            def example = project.tasks.create("example") << {
                def dep = project.configurations.runtime.allDependencies
                def info = project.configurations.runtime.getName()
                def g = project.configurations.runtime.getAllArtifacts()

            }
```

How can i get this  on Java ?

Comment: Do you mean "how do I write this plugin in Java"?

Comment: yes. i find gradle Java API https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/ with method configurations but dont know how use Closure in this method

Answer (score 0):

You can add a task that will write whatever values you like out to a java `Properties` file, like so:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

def generatedResourcesDir = new File(project.buildDir, 'generated-resources')

tasks.withType(Jar).all { Jar jar -> 
    jar.doFirst {
        def props = new Properties()
        props.foobar = 'baz'
        generatedResourcesDir.mkdirs()
        def writer = new FileWriter(new File(generatedResourcesDir, 'build.properties'))
        try {
            props.store(writer, 'build properties')
            writer.flush()
        } finally {
            writer.close()
        }    
    }
} 

sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDir generatedResourcesDir
        }
    }
}

mainClassName = 'BuildProps'
```

Notice that a directory is created in the build output directory of the root project (called generated-resources, though you can call it whatever you want, within reason). The properties file is then written to this directory as a result of running the custom task before any `jar` task. Finally, the generated-resources directory is added to the `resources` source set. This means it will become a resource within the generated jar file and as such can be accessed like any other resource; for example:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

class BuildProps {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (InputStream inputStream = 
                BuildProps.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("build.properties")) {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.load(inputStream);
            System.out.println("Build properties:");
            System.out.println("foobar=" + props.getProperty("foobar", ""));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

which will print:

```
Build properties:
foobar=baz
```

As for your specific desired properties, you could set them like this: replace the line `props.foobar = 'baz'` with the following

```
def dependenciesProp = ''
for (def dependency : project.configurations.runtime.allDependencies) {
    dependenciesProp += dependency.toString() + ','
}
props.dependencies = dependenciesProp

props.runtimename = project.configurations.runtime.name

def artifactsProp = ''
for (def artifact : project.configurations.runtime.allArtifacts) {
    artifactsProp += artifact.toString() + ','
}
props.artifacts = artifactsProp
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer i try your solution and its good but  need use  Java only (without Groovy tasks) . Tasks and code need to be place in Java class not in build.gradle file. I think Java have Gradle API to get this info.